# I read that it is possible to hide panels and tabs on Blender´s interface

Tags: interface

I´ve read on that now it´s possible to hide panels in Blender to simplify the interface. Project Blender 101 cites this although there´s no links to check the code.

On https://developer.blender.org/ I have searched for any example that could help me simplify Blender 2.79a interface. For example, I´d like to hide the dynamics tab property (on the property panel on the right) and also on the tab dynamics on the Tools panel to the left.

How can I do that? Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Blender 101 is an upcoming initiative to simplify Blender interface for future versions. It is only for 2.8+ and is not yet developed, even in current nightlies. As far as I know, once it is out it will require Python coding to create templates/workspaces, so it is not something trivial end users could do at a press of a button, as far as I know.

Comment: Blender 101 at this point is not much more than an idea and an internet platform to discuss it. Nothing official and nothing to download. Also remember that a somewhat "simplified" interface might make things more difficult in the end. Especially if you are a beginner and want to watch (and believe me, you do) a lot of video tutorials.

Comment: I would recommend buying Pie Menu Editor, It's an addon that lets you customize a lot of blender's UI, You can hide panels and even set them to be toggled. Plus it does like 1001 other awesome things :P